# Can't make this site responsive with bootstrap's col classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, responsive

I am using the "col" classes to make the checkboxes responsive... but it's not working... and how does col exactly work? and is there maybe another way to make it responsive?

This is the checkbox:

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 62px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6a8494;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

label:first-of-type {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
  transform: translateX(-40px);
}

label:last-of-type {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
  transform: translateX(40px);
}

label:hover,
input:focus+label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

input:checked+label {
  background-color: #ab576c;
}

input:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <input id="box1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box1">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <input id="box2" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box2">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <input id="box3" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box3">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <input id="box4" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box4">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <input id="box5" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box5">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
```

Comment: What's not working about it? Seems to be working exactly as expected. You are using bootstrap as your grid framework. The `col` class is just what they use to define how many columns you want your elements to span.

Comment: its not responsive.... @APAD1

Comment: Yes it is. If you resize your browser window you will see the checkboxes getting smaller and then at mobile size they stack on top of each other.

Comment: if you make it smaller the word: checkbox 1 , will be cut in half @APAD1

Comment: That's because there is not enough room for the text at that size. Doesn't mean it's not responsive.

Comment: how can i fix that? @APAD1

Comment: You can either adjust the padding of the label at that breakpoint, or you can change the columns to stack earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to adjust the breakpoint at which the checkboxes begin to stack. You can do that by removing the `col-md-2` class from each checkbox. If you do that, the checkboxes will display in 1 column at the smallest breakpoint, display in 2 columns at the `sm` and `md` breakpoints and then at the `lg` breakpoint, they will display inline.

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 62px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6a8494;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

label:first-of-type {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
          transform: translateX(-40px);
}

label:last-of-type {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
          transform: translateX(40px);
}

label:hover, input:focus + label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ab576c;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2"> 
      <input id="box1" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box1">Checkbox 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">  
      <input id="box2" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box2">Checkbox 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2"> 
      <input id="box3" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box3">Checkbox 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2"> 
      <input id="box4" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box4">Checkbox 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2"> 
      <input id="box5" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box5">Checkbox 1</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```